# When file is uploaded need to send an email with attachment with file format

Tags: apex, after-trigger, singleemailmessage, emailmessage, emailfileattachment

I have a task that when i upload a file with excel or pdf or any format at that time it have to send an email with attachment with the file type which i upload .

Below is my code:-

```
trigger contentdocumenttriggers on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    
  List<id> ContentDocumentids = new List<id>();
  for(contentDocumentLink CDLink : trigger.new){
     ContentDocumentids.add(CDLink.ContentDocumentid);  
  }
  system.debug(ContentDocumentids);
  for ( ContentVersion cversion : [SELECT title, 
                                          PathOnClient, 
                                          FileType,
                                          versiondata 
                                          FROM contentversion 
                                          WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :ContentDocumentids  
                                               ]){
     blob WOCFbody = cversion.versiondata;
     system.debug('body : '+WOCFbody+'-----------'+cversion.title);
     Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
     efa1.setFileName(cversion.title+cversion.FileType);
     efa1.setBody(WOCFbody);
     //fileAttachments.add(efa); 
     system.debug(WOCFbody);

    //Apex Single email message
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new 
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
     mail.setUseSignature(false);
     mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'mahesh@example.com' });//Set To Email Address
     mail.setSubject('Test Email With Attachment');//Set Subject
     mail.setHtmlBody('Please find the attachment.');//Set HTML Body
     mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { efa1 });//Set File Attachment
     Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });//Send Email
      system.debug(mail);
   }
}
```

I have tried with above code but its getting like the below screenshot
[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? The Screenshot does not show any error.

Comment: No its not about an error , when i upload a file i have to send email with the same file format like ex:- if i upload an excel file the email have to send with the attchment with the excel format but i receive the email with above screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to add `FileType` as extension without a dot `.` previous to it.

```
efa1.setFileName(cversion.title+cversion.FileType);
```

Also you need `FileExtension` property, not `FileType`, because `FileType` for `.xlsx` is `EXCEL_X`, therefore, you need `FileExtension` which is `xlsx`.

So the final result will be:

```
efa1.setFileName(cversion.title + '.' + cversion.FileExtension);
```

Do not forget to retrieve `FileExtension` in SOQL query.